# What are we trying to [kill]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I am proposing that we burninate [kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kill).

The tag wiki for [kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kill) reads:

> Kill is an operation of removing an object or process from memory so
>   that other processes/variables can use them.

The questions in this tag generally fall into 2 categories:

- A process is being unexpectedly killed (often relating to [sigkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sigkill))
- How do I kill a process?

Nearly all of the questions in the first category do not need [kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kill), as they are not trying to kill a process.

The majority of the questions in the second category are questions like [Really killing a process in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49988), which are potentially off topic and belong on Server Fault, Super User, or their respective operating system site.

The only questions that would benefit from being tagged with [kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kill) would be questions like [How do I kill a process using Vb.NET or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c), which are obviously on-topic here and are perfectly valid questions.

Also, I certainly hope nobody is an expert in [kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kill)ing things.

I am having trouble deciding whether this tag should be burninated or just needs some clean-up.

Comment: It would require some work, but I think manually retagging to more appropriate tags and hoping no user recreates it would be the better plan.

Comment: @icktoofay I'll probably end up marking a bunch as off topic (general computing) anyways so it shouldn't be too much more work to untag at the same time.

Comment: There's something profoundly appropriate about Santa Claus removing a 'kill' tag.

Comment: I don't see your point... you even mention a good usage of the tag. Also, I don't see why nobody can be a `kill` expert, but can be an expert for a lot of other syscalls/operations. Are we trying to remove any tag of the form `function-name`? What makes `kill` less worthy of being a tag than (e.g.)[`stop`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stop), or `min` and `max` [note: they were proposed for burnination and *declined*]? There is a whole bunch of similar generic tags. Either we remove all of them or none.

Comment: @Bakuriu I'd say all of them, with exceptions for maybe a few very complex functions. And for the record, most people were in favour of removing `min` and `max` (or at least replacing them with a more general `extremum` tag), the burninate request was then declined by shog9 with a vague statement that they're not doing any harm and might be helpful to some people.

Comment: @l4mpi That what I'd expect to hear for most of these tags. Not all tags should be great/extremely useful tags. I agree with Shog9 that if a tag isn't causing any harm (e.g. creating noise, being used in the wrong way *all the time* etc.) it can just stay. Also, burninating a tag *does* take time to someone who could spend that time to do something more useful.

Comment: @Bakuriu IMO these tags _are_ used in the wrong way all the time, as they're effectively useless for getting answers - with the exception of the few tags where you actually need real expertise to answer a question and have actual experts following the tags. But tags like min, max, fibs/facs etc are just noise as they don't result in the question getting more or better answers, and are or should be part of the question title anyways. Not sure if they do any harm and need to be removed, but I'd have no problem with them being gone; so if anyone wants to spend time doing this, why stop them?

Comment: Well, assuming this question was a process, if I wanted to kill it I'd simply do `sudo kill 261481` (;

Answer (score 25):

I would assume the intent of this tag was for the [Unix kill](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill) command and nothing else. It is helpful to have a tag for one such specific command and it makes sense to search for all questions related to the "kill" command.

As for killing processes in Windows, this tag is not helpful.

So I don't agree that this tag should get removed, but perhaps clarified that it is only for the Unix kill command with the same name.

Comment: Is the unix kill command ontopic on SO even?

Comment: @PlasmaHH If it is invoked from a program or shell script, it should be on-topic. In other cases, probably not.

Comment: Well, it's a better tag than [ls], in any event.

Comment: @Wooble: If we keep [ls] we might want to keep [w] too ;)

Comment: theres a kill command in sql too

Comment: There are many other commands named kill that don't relate to unix.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: `kill()` is a POSIX C system call too.

Comment: A better tag would be something like [tag:unix-kill], otherwise people will continue using the tag for unrelated concepts.

Comment: @lundin If it's being invoked from a command (i.e. using system()) then it is less about the kill command and more about the mechanism of calling a system command. I'm for the OP.

Comment: It appears that the bottom-line is: we need a consistent policy about how to treat all OS console commands. There are similar tags for [tag:ls] and many more. To me, it seems that these commands can be used in various programming-purposes, but they are indeed not directly related to programming.

Comment: @alk so... we need a tag for each call defined in the POSIX C?

Comment: @Lundin, what about the tag `shell` contain all those tags? It seems more simple than `unix-utils` (`ls` wiki says it is a "A utility in Unix-like systems...").

Comment: Shouldn't the tag then be renamed to `unix-kill`?

Answer (score 11):

I think this tag is useless. Either [sigkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sigkill) should be used for specific issues with this OS signal or, for general process-killing [process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process) should be sufficient. The sole fact of interacting with processes is the most relevant information. The fact whether it's killing it, or reading its stdout is not that important to have a tag for it. IMHO people usually are experts in interacting with processes, not with just killing them.

Answer (score 3):

I think on-topic questions in this tag should refer to `kill` in a unix context which relates to a specific system of signals(SIGTERM, SIGHUP, etc.) employed by the kernel for process management and in some cases interprocess communication. Not all of these signals are directly related to killing a process and I could see questions related to designing signal APIs, IPC, and building software that interrelates with various shells/shell scripts being taggable.

This its actually quite a complex topic with lots of opinions, best practices, and traps. I don't think it should be removed completely but, it does have high potential for misapplication.

questions such *"How do I kill this process?"*, *"When I kill this in process manager it doesn't respond?*", and/or anything related to windows/non-mono .NET are probably off topic better served by [kill-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kill-process)