# Can we kill [kill]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kill) it with fire!

There are a lot of questions on a lot of different types of killing. Android activities, C++ kill signal, Linux process killing, iOS background apps, C# list of processes... And those were the last 5 questions asked.

[There was a question asked last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261481/what-are-we-trying-to-kill) where one of the conclusions was to reserve this tag for the Unix `kill` command. In that case can we rename it to `unix-kill`?

Comment: I don't think that the usage of the kill command is actually in the programmers skillset. System administrator of course, but I don't expect a programmer knowing about it...

Comment: Well I mean if someone's asking for help about a scipt or something that uses the command? It's unlikely to be popular though, but it might be used.

Comment: That's kinda depressing @Braiam, thankfully everyone doesn't stick to rigidly defined job roles as defined by a single person so I can assure you that programmers do have to know about the kill command occasionally.

Comment: @Ben but is not necesary for a programmer to *know* about it. A programmer could deal with the kernel API to kill process directly instead of using a tool, if they want. That's why I say such tag is not really necessary.